# Stripe element.create: Cannot read property 'create' of null

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

So I want to create my own card elements using the elements.create() function in stripe in my form and not use the CardElement provided by Stripe.
However, when I use useElements() hook to create an element and mount the element, it is giving me an error that "create cannot be used with null"

The code snippet of my form is below:

```
const ElementsForm = ({ price, name, image }) => {
 const stripe = useStripe();
 const elements = useElements();

 var cardNumberElement = elements.create('cardNumber');    //this creates the custom element
 cardNumberElement.mount('#card-number-element');

const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe!.confirmCardPayment(response.client_secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: cardNumberElement!,
        billing_details: {
          name: input.cardholderName,
          address: {
            line1: input.streetAddress,
            postal_code: input.postalCode,
            city: input.city,
            state: input.state,
            country: country,
          },
          email: input.recipientEmail,
          //phone: input.recipientNumber,
        },
      },
    });
 return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-3/4">
 <label>
         <span>Card number</span>
         <div id="card-number-element" className="field"></div>
 </label>

</form>
```

This is not the complete code but the parts that are giving me an error are above. Why am I not able to create an element by this method?

Comment: What do you mean by "not use the CardElement provided by Stripe"? You say this but your snippet uses the `CardElement` created by `elements` and you mount it to a DOM node. The error sounds like you're calling `elements.create()` without a `type` somewhere, but that's not shown here.

Comment: There is a default CardElement in stripe and I'm not using that. Im trying to create a card element so that I can give it custom styling. Here's a reference to the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=cardNumber